# Encoding categorical variables such that both the presence as well as the position of characters matter in literal strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, ordinal

Let's assume we have a dataframe whose last column is made up of literal strings such as the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "col1": ["C", "A", "B"],
            "col2": [4, 1.7, 1],
            "col3": ["SHRTYPPS", "PGYTCCCKAR", "VPCCYCCARE"],
        }
    )
```

Note that both 1) the presence of a character in a string and 2) the position at which it is located within the string matter.

One-hot-encoding the last column follows:

```
col3_lst = [list(i) for i in df.col3]
ids, U = pd.factorize(np.concatenate(col3_lst))
df_new = pd.DataFrame([np.isin(U, i) for i in col3_lst], columns=U).astype(int)
pd.concat([df, df_new], axis=1).drop(["col3"], axis=1)
```

which would result in:

```
  col1  col2  S  H  R  T  Y  P  G  C  K  A  V  E
0    C   4.0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
1    A   1.7  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
2    B   1.0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1
```

However, as you can see the order is not regarded accordingly. Is there anyway to inject the information about the position of the character in the corresponding string into the output dataframe? For example, if there are four C's in the last string, we need to capture the factual information that the letter is present in positions 3rd, 4th, 6th, and 7th as evident. I am looking for something like the following:

```
  col1  col2     position_1    posistion_2    position_3    position_4     position_5  ....  
0    C   4.0         19             8              18           20            25       ....
1    A   1.7         16             7              25           20            3        ....
2    B   1.0         22             16             3            3             25       ....
```

, where each numerical label of encoded columns, `$position_{i}$`, belongs to the position of the following character in the English alphabet; i.e. 1 for A, 2 for B, etc...

Or even better, something like the following:

```
  col1  col2     position_1_A   position_1_B  ...  posistion_2_A   posistion_2_B  ...  position_3_A   position_3_B  ...  position_4_A   position_4_B ...
0    C   4.0           0             0        ...        0               0        ...       0               0       ...            0            0    ...
1    A   1.7           0             0        ...        0               0        ...       0               0       ...            0            0    ...
2    B   1.0           0             0        ...        0               0        ...       0               0       ...            0            0    ...
```

Thank you,

Comment: Could you please add the desired output for this example? Because I am not sure, if I get how it suppose to work.

Comment: That's a good question. Let me see if I can figure that out.

Comment: Here it is, I edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, something like this should do the trick:

```py
result = df["col3"].str.upper()\
    .str.extractall("(.)")\
    .unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)\
    .add_prefix('position_')
result.applymap(lambda x: ord(x) - 64 if pd.notna(x) else x)
```

In the first step we extract all of the chars (I used `extractall("(.)")` instead of `split("")` to not deal with additional characters (\n).

In the second one we map our letters to numbers.

The results look something like the this:

```
match   position_0  position_1  position_2  position_3  position_4  position_5  position_6  position_7  position_8  position_9
0       19          8           18          20          25          16          16          19          NaN         NaN
1       16          7           25          20          3           3           3           11          1           18.0
2       22          16          3           3           25          3           3           1           18          5.0
```

EDIT: If you want to do one hot_encoding use `pd.get_dummies()`

```
result = df["col3"].str.upper()\
    .str.extractall("(.)")\
    .unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)\
    .add_prefix('position_')
pd.get_dummies(result)
```

Which could give you:

```
    position_0_P    position_0_S    position_0_V    ... position_9_R
0   0               1               0               ... 0
1   1               0               0               ... 1
2   0               0               1               ... 0
```

EDIT 2:

If you already have the missings encoded for example as `.`, and you want to encode them as missings with ordinal encoding, you must replace `.` with `np.nan`:

```
result = df["col3"].str.upper()\
    .str.extractall("(.)")\
    .unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)\
    .add_prefix('position_')\
    .replace('.',np.nan)
```

Everything else stays the same.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "col1": ["C", "A", "B", "D"],
            "col2": [4, 1.7, 1, 12],
            "col3": ["SHRTYPPS", "PGYTCCCKAR", "VPCCYCCARE", "HY.RT..CCTCC"],
        }
    )

result = df["col3"].str.upper().str.extractall("(.)").unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1).add_prefix('position_').replace('.',np.nan)
result.applymap(lambda x: ord(x) - 64 if pd.notna(x) else x)

#match  position_0  position_1  position_2  ... position_11
#0      19          8           18.0        ... NaN
#1      16          7           25.0        ... NaN
#2      22          16          3.0         ... NaN
#3      8           25          NaN         ... 3.0

pd.get_dummies(result)

#   position_0_H    position_0_P    position_0_S    position_0_V    ... position_10_C   position_11_C
#0  0               0               1               0               ... 0               0
#1  0               1               0               0               ... 0               0
#2  0               0               0               1               ... 0               0
#3  1               0               0               0               ... 1               1
```

EDIT 3:

If you want to treat some group - for example in parentheses - as one character, you should modify the regex to capture it as a single group. In this case ordinal encoding, as shown above won't work (since it takes positions of single letter in alphabet). But one-hot encoding should work well. For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "col1": ["C", "D"],
            "col2": [4, 12],
            "col3": ["SHRTYPPS(hr3)", "HY.RT..CCTCC(hr4)"],
        }
    )

result = df["col3"].str.extractall("(\(.*\)|.)")\
            .unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1)\
            .add_prefix('position_')\
            .replace('.',np.nan)\
            .apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[\(\)]+', '', regex = True))

pd.get_dummies(result)

#   position_0_H    position_0_S    ... position_11_C   position_12_hr4
#0  0               1               ... 0               0
#1  1               0               ... 1               1
```

The last apply is just to get rid of parenthesis in column names, it could be removed, if name `position_12_(hr4)` is better then `position_12_hr4`.

Comment: Thank you, I actually do have missing positions in the form of "." instead of character like HY.RT..CCTCC which I am planning to show an NAN values in the corresponding cells. Can you incorporate that also into your solution? I will wait to see if there is any other solution intended to produce the second desired format. ---Sincerely,

Comment: Done, you simply replace missings with `nan`

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and time,

Comment: Hi Daniel, I want to follow on your answer. Let's assumes some of the strings appearing in col3 of the dataframe have a form like "VPCCYCCARE(hr3)" where the substring "(hr3)" should be considered in the same exact footing as any other individual letter in the string. How the solution would change if we have such random substrings that always are contained in parentheses and must be dealt with just like any other character, i.e. with a column header of "position_11_hr3 which will have an encoded value of 1 since there is (hr3) object inside the 11th position of the string?

Comment: The easiest way would be replacing the group with some not used character, fe.
`df["col3"] = df["col3"].str.replace('(hr3)', '#', regex=False)` and then continue with code above. Better strategy would be changing regex in `extractall("(.)")` to capture both situations, but I am not an expert in regex - you might ask question on SO, just with that.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. It should look like this:
`result = df["col3"].str.extractall("(\(.*\)|.)").unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1).add_prefix('position_').replace('.',np.nan)`. If you want to get rid of parenthesis in column names you would do `result = result.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'[\(\)]+', '', regex = True))`
And then `pd.get_dummies(result)`

Comment: Hi Daniel, we have some new data like N(Gla)S(Gla)CPwHPWC(nh2) as an item in column 3 of the dataframe. Is there anyway to extend your solution to include strings that have multiple parenthesis in them, i.e. meaning column labels such as position_1_Gla, position_4_Gla, position_12_nh2 and....?

Comment: You should probably modify the regex, if you won't have nested parentheses, it might look like this: `extractall("(\([^\)]*\)|.)")` since it will ensure that the group will end at the nearest closing parenthesis. But I am not an expert on regex - there might be an easier way to do this.